# how to add the method and the keywords like greaterthan... on ProductRepo extend CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-ee-8

this is the entity

[image]

the problem is when I want to work with a keyword I must writ it with own hands

Comment: Do you need to do custom query with method name like  `findByGreaterThan()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how else something in your code could get written except by your hands. Could you clarify what your question is? Please also share code as text formatted as code, not images.

Comment: your question is not clear... seems your problem is that you don't have any auto-completion via your IDE for this keyword ? Right .?

Comment: yes the ide is sts 4.6,I'm not good in English so I can't explain what the problem clarify